# Discord.py How to make a command happen a set amount of times

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm currently making a fun command called tornado that takes a user and moves them around a bunch of voice channels. What I want to be able to do is make the command **>tornado @Blah#1234 5** and have them be moved through the 6 voice channels 5 times before they aare returned to voice channel 0 (the initial voice channel). So far I am able to command **>tornado @Blah#1234** and they are moved through the 6 voice channels once and then are returned to their original voice channel. Any help is appreciated!

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def tornado(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  voice1 = bot.get_channel(824745972768702525)
  voice2 = bot.get_channel(729916324272144439)
  voice3 = bot.get_channel(729927718296223839)
  voice4 = bot.get_channel(775807325641375744)
  voice5 = bot.get_channel(729958198957834290)
  voice6 = bot.get_channel(729958233669632020)
  voice0 = member.voice.channel
  await member.move_to(voice1) ; sleep(0.1)
  await member.move_to(voice2) ; sleep(0.1)
  await member.move_to(voice3) ; sleep(0.1)
  await member.move_to(voice4) ; sleep(0.1)
  await member.move_to(voice5) ; sleep(0.1)
  await member.move_to(voice6) ; sleep(0.1)
  await member.move_to(voice0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a very simple `for` loop. Here's an exemple :

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def tornado(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    voice1 = bot.get_channel(824745972768702525)
    voice2 = bot.get_channel(729916324272144439)
    voice3 = bot.get_channel(729927718296223839)
    voice4 = bot.get_channel(775807325641375744)
    voice5 = bot.get_channel(729958198957834290)
    voice6 = bot.get_channel(729958233669632020)
    voice0 = member.voice.channel
    for i in range(5):
        await member.move_to(voice1) ; sleep(0.1)
        await member.move_to(voice2) ; sleep(0.1)
        await member.move_to(voice3) ; sleep(0.1)
        await member.move_to(voice4) ; sleep(0.1)
        await member.move_to(voice5) ; sleep(0.1)
        await member.move_to(voice6) ; sleep(0.1)
    await member.move_to(voice0)
```

But there's a more simple way :

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def tornado(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    voices = [
        824745972768702525,
        729916324272144439,
        729927718296223839,
        775807325641375744,
        729958198957834290,
        729958233669632020,
    ]
    voice0 = member.voice.channel
    for i in range(5):
        for voice in voices:
            await member.move_to(bot.get_channel(voice)
            sleep(0.1)
    await member.move_to(voice0)
```

What I'm doing is simply moving the member through all the voice channels in the `voices` list (second `for` loop), 5 times (first `for` loop). And, at the end, return him to his original voice channel.